# SlideDown/ SlideUp Toggle 2 divs

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs, one visible, one not. I want to toggle the visibility by clicking a link but when I toggle the second time, my first div doesnt appears.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-extra">
  <a href="#" id="toggle-to-advanced">Toggle to red</a>
</div>

<div class="search-advanced">
  <a href="#" id="toggle-to-normal">Toggle to black</a>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.search-advanced{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#toggle-to-normal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.search-advanced').slideUp('normal').queue( function(){
        jQuery('.search-extra').slideDown('normal');
    });
});

jQuery('#toggle-to-advanced').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.search-extra').slideUp('normal').queue( function(){
        jQuery('.search-advanced').slideDown('normal');
    });
});​
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/rekQ9/

Comment: try on for the event listener. jQuery('#toggle-to-normal').on("click",...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `queue`, you can use the callback function on the slides to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/rekQ9/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#toggle-to-normal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.search-advanced').slideUp('normal',function(){
        jQuery('.search-extra').slideDown('normal');
    });
});

jQuery('#toggle-to-advanced').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.search-extra').slideUp('normal', function(){
        jQuery('.search-advanced').slideDown('normal');
    });
});
```